# Class cast exception while messages pass through Kafka Streams API

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am getting class cast exception while messages pass through Kafka Streams API,

Exception is:

> java.lank/ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode

My Stream Code is :

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "BranchingTopics-API");
    config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "samsmembershipkafka.dev.cloud.wal-mart.com:9092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
    final Serializer<JsonNode> jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
    final Deserializer<JsonNode> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
    final Serde<JsonNode> jsonSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(jsonSerializer,
            jsonDeserializer);

    /*
     * config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, jsonSerde);
     * config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
     * jsonSerde);
     */

    // Building Stream
    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    KStream<String, JsonNode> textlines = builder.stream("MainTopic");

    Predicate<String, JsonNode> isAddComment = (key, value) -> value
            .get("header").toString().contains("/addComment");
    Predicate<String, JsonNode> is1M1C = (key, value) -> value
            .get("header").toString().contains("/1Member1Account");
    Predicate<String, JsonNode> isLostOrStolen = (key, value) -> (value
            .get("header").toString()
            .contains("/changeCardStatus?action=STOLEN") || value
            .get("header").toString()
            .contains("/changeCardStatus?action=LOST"));

    KStream<String, JsonNode>[] topicTypes = textlines.branch(isAddComment,
            is1M1C, isLostOrStolen);

    topicTypes[0].to(stringSerde, jsonSerde, "CommentsTopic");
    topicTypes[1].to(stringSerde, jsonSerde, "OneMemberOneAccountTopic");
    topicTypes[2].to(stringSerde, jsonSerde, "LostOrStolenTopic");

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);

    streams.start();
}
```

Comment: What's the complete stack trace? Seems you are using the wrong Serde somewhere. From you code snippet, I would assume you need to specify JSON-Serde when reading the topic `builder.stream(stringSerde, jsonSerde, "MainTopic");` -- I guess you would need to specify correct serdes for other operations, too. Look carefully at the stack trace to figure out which operator throw the exception.

Comment: yes that was the problem, working now, Thanks

Comment: Put my comment as answer so you can mark question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using the wrong `Serde` somewhere. From you code snippet, I would assume you need to specify JSON-Serde when reading the topic:

```java
builder.stream(stringSerde, jsonSerde, "MainTopic");
```

I guess you would need to specify correct `Serde`s for other operations, too. Look carefully at the stack trace to figure out which operator throw the exception